# Apply custom projectionmatrix (to texturecoordinate) in GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl

I want to view a flat fullscreen texture as it is spherical, by transforming it in a postprocess shader.

I figure I have to apply a projectionmatrix to the texture coordinate in the shader.

I found this website: http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html which learns me a lot about the inners of the projectionmatrix.

But how do I apply it? I thought I would have to multiply the third row of the projection matrix to the texture coordinate with a calculated z value added to make it spherical. My efforts don't show any result though.

EDIT: I see the same issue here: http://lists.openscenegraph.org/pipermail/osg-users-openscenegraph.org/2008-April/009765.html

Comment: "*view a flat fullscreen texture as it is spherical*" So you want to map a rectangle to a sphere? I don't really see how projection matrices are going to help you here.

Comment: I simplified the problem because I didn't get a response at first. It's called projective texture mapping I've learned, in my case adding a texture in postprocess (animating a skycube to be precise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think after you multiply text coords by projection matrix you have to make a perspective division and move from 3D to 2D (since the texture is 2D). This is the same as with shadow mapping.

```
// in fragment shader:
vec4 proj = uniformModelViewProjMatrix * tex_coords;
proj.xyz /= proj.w;
proj.xyz += vec3(1.0);
proj.xyz *= 0.5;
vec4 col = texture2D(sampler, proj.xy);
```

or look at http://www.ozone3d.net/tutorials/glsl_texturing_p08.php (for `texture2DProj`)

Comment: That did help me along a little, I did not know the practice for this. If I understand correctly, I use a specific "w" for the actual transform, where "w" is applied by FOV (with use of pythagoras I made some calculations).